# settings file's variable manages from database in django

Tags: python, django

Is possible to load variable's value from database dynamically in Django?

I'm new in Django. I tried to give the value to this settings.py's file variable from admin panel.

#### models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

#### settings.py

```py
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '' #How to set this value from admin panel dynamically
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = ''
```

I have to install 'captch' app in my project so, need to set the value of necessary key but i am trying to set this value from the database. can i change value from the database?( If you have to new idea to implement this dynamically then also please suggest me.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have code that queries a model in `settings.py`, as the database connection is still being set up at that point.

Comment: That's the problem.Sir, any another solution to give value dynamically in settings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is possible to load variable's value from database dynamically in Django?

Yes. You can use an app like [`django-constance`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) to support dynamic settings via the admin UI at runtime.

However, I don't think it's clear from your models that this is what you're attempting to do. If the Recaptcha keys are different for each `Person` instance, those aren't settings (or constants) at all, they're just per-Person values and should be treated like normal model fields.

If each Person can have their own keys, but the system *also* needs default values to use for Person instances that don't have keys, then it would make sense to store a set of keys as settings and potentially a different set per Person (though this isn't how your models are written currently, since those key fields are not nullable).